# npm add remote package from git and compile typescript on npm install?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have two projects that share a types package dedicated to that project, and I import it from my github like this:

```
"myproject-types": "git+https://<my-key>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myprojecttypes/myprojecttypes.git"
```

When I use this in `Angular`, it works perfectly fine but when I use this on my backend `NestJS` I get errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'myproject-types/src/enums/session-event.enum'
```

It's because the build script I run does not compile these typescript files, because the package only containing typescript files.

This is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/myproject-types"
  ]
}
```

I can't really understand why doesn't it compile the typescript while nestjs typescript files are compiled on build.

Is there a way to compile the package typescript so js files will be created upon `npm install` in `node_modules`?